# Echo to /dev/ttyUSB0 produces no results

Tags: linux, bash, printing, printer, port

I'm trying to make a POS thermal printer work with linux. As far as I understand it, I can send data to print directly to the printer throgh a port - it's an RS232 with USB adapter. It gets connected fine, detected as a `pl2303 converter` and shown to be `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Main problem is - contrary to most information I was able to find online, `cat`ing the file and then `echo`ing to it (tried many combinations of data and commands) has no results, including nothing being printed. The terminal with cat is just waiting and not showing anyhting - no gibberish, nothing. Echo returns no errors either.

Being totally incompetent with "low level" stuff like this I tried everything I was able to find in Google to no avail. Something that I was able to find that might be an explanation, was this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459466/pl2303-pl2303x-usb-serial-driver
I'm pretty sure my hardware also "commonly uses 3 pins", as well as has DTR = 1 (and every other pin with the same value if that helps).

I am unable to try his solution though, as I don't really understand it nor am I running any C code really - I'm trying to print from the commandline.

Any help is appreaciated - I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please provide the POS thermal printer make, model, & possibly any P/N's you have from the RS232 cable. That connector is SO common that it can be wired MANY different ways. Printers documentation might be able to clear that up

Comment: @gregg The printer is [SNBC BTP-2002NP](https://www.crs-usa.com/products/printers/retired-printer-models/printer--btp-2002np) (when installing drivers on Windows it also added `(S)` at the end), there's also some [documentation available](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/675671/Snbc-Btp-2002np.html).

I wasn't able to find much about it beyond that unfortunately. It seems like it's made by some random Chinese company without a brand and then sold under many brands, and this specific model seems to have dissappeared from the internet...